# Java Set Multiple Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement

I know that this is a general question and I have researched about this all day long, but I would like to know if it's possible to set multiple objects using a 'for' statement and avoiding multiple if-elses. So I have this:

1. I have a String[] array with 50 column names.
2. I have to iterate this array and create a custom object for each name. This custom object has some common data but there are 2 properties that might differ by column (for example I have a columnType property which has to be set in particular for each object I create). Then I have to add these objects to an ArrayList.

So how could I set my objects (an object represents a column) for each column name I have without creating them one by one and then adding them to an ArrayList 'manually' or if I use a 'for' how to avoid those if-else to set the type?

```
 ArrayList<MyColumnObj> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyColumnObj>;
 for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        Button btn = new HeaderButton(this);
        btn.setPosition(i);
        btn.setColumnName(columns[i]);

        int columnWidth = 150;

        MyColumnObj myColumnObject = new MyColumnObj(btn, columnWidth);
        myColumnObject.setTag(i);

        if (columns[i].equals("Column 1") {
           myColumnObject.setType("Column Number");
         } else if (columns[i].equals("Column 2") {
           myColumnObject.setType("Column Colored");
         } 
         ...
         else if (columns[i].equals("Column 50") {
           myColumnObject.setType("Column Text");
          }


        arrayList.add(myColumnObject);
    }
```

I would appreciate any answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. I wrote the code here on stackoverflow.

Comment: What type of data is stored in Array?

Comment: It's ArrayList<MyColumnObj>

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, String>` where you map the column names to the `setType` parameters. Then you just do like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    Button btn = new HeaderButton(this);
    btn.setPosition(i);
    btn.setColumnName(columns[i]);

    int columnWidth = 150;

    MyColumnObj myColumnObject = new MyColumnObj(btn, columnWidth);
    myColumnObject.setTag(i);
    myColumnObject.setType(typeMap.get(columns[i]); // typeMap contains your mappings

    arrayList.add(myColumnObject);
}
```

Comment: This is that I was thinking too. Simple solution.

Comment: I was thinking about this too. But in the future we might add new properties. And how would I handle that case? It would be hard to add a map every time a new particular property is added.

Comment: You just create new maps for each property or you use a `Map<String, String[]>` where the `String[]` holds all your properties (don't have to be Strings, you could also just use `Object[]`). Or use a `List` instead of an array. (`Map<String, List<Object>>`)

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful, if your Column names are consective like Array-index. Then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    Button btn = new HeaderButton(this);
    btn.setPosition(i);
    btn.setColumnName(columns[i]);

    int columnWidth = 150;

    MyColumnObj myColumnObject = new MyColumnObj(btn, columnWidth);
    myColumnObject.setTag(i);

    if(columns[i].equals("Column" + i){
    myColumnObject.setType("Type" + i);
    }

    arrayList.add(myColumnObject);
}
```

Comment: it was just a rough example. The types are different.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your data in map, key(Column) value (type)
then select it